# How to force passing parameter to the constructor using dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

To ensure proper data initialization and ensure data sanitation, we used immutable objects. To ensure that they were initialized, we passed them through the constructor.

```
UserManager userManager = new UserManager(obj);

class UserManager
{
   object _obj;

    public UserManager(object o)
    {
        _obj = o;
    }
}
```

In `UserManager` class we have one constructor. So it forces us to pass the name parameter whenever we create the instance of the class `UserManager`.

Now we started using dependency injection and we are passing `UserManager` as a dependency, in this way are not able to force to pass name parameter.

Is there any way we can do that. We are trying to implement the same in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Where will `name` come from?

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question in its current state is also incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then edit the question to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is actually being asked.

Comment: Please add some details to your question. But it seems you want to configure DI for the nested dependencies. You want to inject UserManager and you want that UserManager to already have injected dependency.

Comment: You should describe what `object o` is for type of dependency. Is it a service (abstraction) that contains behavior? Does it contain data that is fixed and available when the application starts (e.g. configuration values)? Does it contain runtime data that might be different for each request? Do describe this nature and show concrete examples, because the answer to your question depends on the nature of the injected object.